# Fill button on click is not working once a if else statement is used

Tags: javascript

I have a star icon from Google. I made it into a button. When it is clicked, I'd like it to have a fill color. I am able to do such when I use javascript and an event listener. However, if I add an `if else` to the event listener, it no longer works. Any help?

```js
const star = document.getElementById('star');
star.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (star.style.fontVariationSettings === "'FILL' 0") {
    star.style.fontVariationSettings = "'FILL' 10";
  } else {
    star.style.fontVariationSettings = "'FILL' 0";
  }
});
```

```css
.star {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 24
}

.star {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: var(--check-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="star" class="material-symbols-outlined star">star</button>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

</html>
```

I was expecting the if else statement to work properly.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon CSS `font-variations` for the first time, and being just as confused as to why none of the examples do anything: All of this is based on [Google's Material Symbols custom font](https://fonts.google.com/icons), which provides some custom font characteristics (fill (FILL) and grade (GRAD)) that can be specified with `font-variations`. Normal fonts only have weight, width, slant, italics and optical sizing properties, and since the custom font isn't packaged in the examples, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the `if`. It's your `background: none;` that prevents `fontVariationSettings` from working.

```js
const star = document.getElementById('star');
star.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (star.style.fontVariationSettings === "'FILL' 0") {
    star.style.fontVariationSettings = "'FILL' 10";
  } else {
    star.style.fontVariationSettings = "'FILL' 0";
  }
});
```

```css
.star {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 24
}

.star {
  border: none;
  color: var(--check-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="star" class="material-symbols-outlined star">star</button>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The style setting is being canonicalized after you assign it, and it's using double quotes rather than single quotes.

```js
const star = document.getElementById('star');
star.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (star.style.fontVariationSettings === '"FILL" 0') {
    star.style.fontVariationSettings = '"FILL" 10';
  } else {
    star.style.fontVariationSettings = '"FILL" 0';
  }
});
```

```css
.star {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 24
}

.star {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: var(--check-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="star" class="material-symbols-outlined star">star</button>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Instead of assigning to the style, it would be better to use a class that you toggle.

```js
const star = document.getElementById('star');
star.addEventListener('click', () => {
  star.classList.toggle("fill10");
});
```

```css
.star {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 24;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: var(--check-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star.fill10 {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 10, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 24;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="star" class="material-symbols-outlined star">star</button>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: It's `background: none` that prevents it from fulfilling the expectations.

Comment: That's a separate problem. In my tests, the `if` statement never succeeded because the quotes didn't match.

Comment: @LajosArpad Barmar's solution using classes is still much more robust in general. Checking for CSS properties being a certain value can lead to cross-browser wackiness pretty quickly. Also really just wackiness in general, as in this example.

Comment: @TARN4T1ON robust or not, the style is not applied here on the star icon. It's not applied before nor during the click. This answer is misleading and the snippets inside of it are disfunctional and the reason for this answer being less than useful is that it leaves `background: none;` inside the CSS, without which, by the way the whole stuff would work properly. Hence, the "fix" in this answer is not fixing anything. We see a refactor, but the question is not addressed and the bug is still in the snippet.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm not really familiar with the `font-variation-settings` style, so I didn't know there was interaction between it and the `background` style. My answer was just directed at the way they implemented their `if` statement. I assumed that the style setting works as intended.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that makes sense. But your answer still needs an edit, because it lacks the solution to the question. I was not familiar with `font-variation-settings` either, but I played around it until a solution was found.